# useEffect infiniteloop refreshing data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I'm working with useEffect and useState to get data from an async function. I'm calling this useEffect every time the playlists state gets changed. This is really inefficient since my code goes through an infinite loop and I can't console log anything. However, I want to be able to update data without refreshing the page, so this was my logic. Is there a more efficient way to do this and get data without refreshing the page. I don't want to call onMount([]) every time, because I would have to refresh.

```
const [playlists, getPlaylists] = useState([])

useEffect(()=>{
    let mounted = true
    GetUserPlaylists().then(data => {
            if (mounted){
                getPlaylists(data)
                }
            })
    return () => {mounted = false};
},[playlists])

async function GetUserPlaylists() {
    var user = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser()
    user = user.attributes.email
    try{
    const playlists = await API.graphql(graphqlOperation(queries.getUserPlaylist, {id: user}))
    return playlists.data.getUser.playlists.items
    } catch(err){
        console.log(err)
    }
}

export default GetListenerPlaylists
```

My getUserPlaylists function returns the data from an Amplify GraphQL Query.

Comment: Just pass the playlist as a prop instead. How exactly does the result of `GetUserPlaylists()` change?

Comment: You need to update the state some other way. Just query the API every five seconds or so. Or every minute? Anyway, use `setInterval()` instead.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you need to read a bit more about how useEffect and useState work. First naming in coding is important. You can name the setter function whatever you want but since it is setting the state by naming it getPlaylist you just confuse yourself and maybe other dev in future. By proving playlist argument for useEffect you tell react to re run the function inside the useEffect to and by changing the playlist inside the useEffect callback you get an infinite loop.
To fix your problem you have to have your network call (fetch request) inside the useEffect and to meet the realtime feature the simplest way that come to mind is having a setInterval and polling the API every N seconds.
Finally get rid of the playlist argument for the useEffect function since when you  change the the state your component get re-rendered.